# is it possible to make automatic transaction on solana?

Tags: anchor, rust

Is this possible that user can set a certain amount of money can be deducted from their account in a certain time automatically just by signing the transaction only once? Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

Clockwork lets you do this. It's an automation engine that lets you schedule transactions.

Check out [this repo](https://github.com/clockwork-xyz/examples/tree/main/subscriptions) for an example of on-chain usage. Here a Pda is given delegation over a token account, making it able to sign transactions that deduct from the account. The transaction is then delegated to a clockwork thread which runs it at the set times. This makes the entire operation permissionless as it doesn't need the user's signature to run.

You can also check out clockwork's [typescript package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@clockwork-xyz/sdk).

Otherwise check out [Stache](https://stache.kaistack.com) by Kaizencorps. It's really cool smart-wallet but is also still new and under development so be careful about that, but it has exactly what you need for a simple case like this.

Answer (score 0):

Time based transactions usually require whats called a "crank" to process asynchronously. This is usually something like a CRON executed serverless function, or a long-lived process that internally knows when to sleep and when to execute.

Unfortunately a user cannot do this on their own with a signature because Solana transaction signature has very quick expirations due to their requiring a valid recent block hash from the live network.

To accomplish something like this, you would need some sort of multisig process where the user signs their portion of the transaction and the authoritative keypair you the crank application would sign the rest - consequently meeting the threshold and being able to send the transaction for confirmation.